# Saving ListView Items upon application exit/orientation change

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio-2.3, saving-data

I have a simple ToDo list in which I am trying to save the Todo's (List items) upon application exit and upon the orientation change. I have tried some code and it doesn't seem to save anything. Here is my MainActivity.

```
package com.example.android.todolist;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    //Variables
    Button addTodo;
    ListView listView;
    EditText itemInput;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    TextView myTodoList;
    String stringInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Add custom font to title
        myTodoList = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvMyTodoList);
        Typeface textViewFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"High Tide - Demo.ttf");
        myTodoList.setTypeface(textViewFont);

        //Find views by ID
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvTodoView);
        itemInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etAddItem);
        addTodo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAddTodo);

        //Set adapter onto ListView
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //On long click action
        listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                adapter.remove(adapter.getItem(position));
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                return true;
            }
        });

        //Add strikethrough to on click action, and remove strikethrough when clicked again
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {

                TextView addStrikethroughToListItem = (TextView) view;

                if ((addStrikethroughToListItem.getPaintFlags() & Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG) == 0)
                {
                    addStrikethroughToListItem.setPaintFlags(addStrikethroughToListItem.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                else
                {
                    addStrikethroughToListItem.setPaintFlags(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    //Method to add item to ListView
    public void addItemToList(View view)
    {
        Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
        String emptyItem = "Please enter an item";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        if (itemInput.length() > 1)
        {
            adapter.add(itemInput.getText().toString().trim());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            itemInput.setText(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(appContext, emptyItem, duration).show();
        }
    }
private static int ix = 0;

@Override
protected void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    submitPrefs();
    Log.e(TAG,"OnPause executed");
}

@Override
protected void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    getStoredPrefs();
    Log.e(TAG,"onResume executed");
}

private void submitPrefs()
{
    SharedPreferences pref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsX",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putString("InputX","My Iteration" + ix);
    editor.commit();
    ix++;
}

private void getStoredPrefs()
{
    SharedPreferences pref = getBaseContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPrefsX",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String s = pref.getString("InputX", "Not set yet");
    Log.e(TAG,"My State == " + s);
}
}
```

I haven't added any code to the onBackPressed method because I haven't got to that point yet. Right now I'm interested in the onSaveInstanceState method and the onRestoreInstanceState method.

Here is my XML.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.todolist.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sample_background3">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMyTodoList"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/my_todo_s"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.512"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:hint="@string/enter_todo_here"
        android:id="@+id/etAddItem"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:layout_width="261dp"
        android:labelFor="@+id/etAddItem"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvTodoView"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddTodo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="addItemToList"
        android:text="@string/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/etAddItem"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/lvTodoView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/lvTodoView"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvTodoView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="373dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvMyTodoList"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Any ideas on what I have done wrong? The application isn't saving anything. The only time I find my Todo's still in the List is when I press the home button and re-open the app. If I close the app any other way, nothing is saved.

I have tried using SharedPreferences and I didn't have any luck. I asked on a forum if SharedPreferences was suitable for this action and I was told it was OK. I also asked about an SQLite database and I was told that it's not needed in this case. I have also tried various tutorials on YouTube and nothing has worked. The code shown above is the last method I have tried. I can't seem to find anything else to try.

Also, since this is my very first app, I would be very grateful if anybody can give me some general feedback on what I've done whether it's on the structure, the code or just any suggestions anybody has in hope to get rid of any bad practices I may have displayed.

Home Button Pressed
[image: Home Button Pressed]

Re-Open App from Home Button Close

[image: Re-Open app from Home Button Close]

Back Button Press

[image: Back Button Pressed]

Comment: Have you put a trace on whether `onSaveInstanceState` is actually being fired? Or tried `onPause` instead?

Comment: No I don’t think so. How would I put a trace on that? Should I add a log maybe? I tried onPause too but I was probably making the same mistake I am now. Nothing worked.

Comment: What I meant was send some messages to your log with Log.d(). or Log.e(). Don't forget to remove them in your finished code! You can filter the Log in android studio. With these messages you can trace through your program and see what methods are being executed and which one are not.

Comment: Ok thanks. I’ll check that out.

Comment: I've just tried this and I have added the necessary Logs. Both onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState get called. OnSaveInstanceState gets called when I push the home button, and it works. The onRestoreInstanceState gets called when I rotate the screen, but does not save the data. Code has been updated in the relevant methods. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was not that you could not save the data to a SharedPreference. The problem is you wanted to persist the lists data. Sorry I didn't catch that the first time.

I'm assuming you what the user to be able to close the app and when the user reopens the app the the todo list is populated with the data from the last session.

A `ListView` will not persist the data for one session to the next. You must do it your self. Your code will need quite a bit of work to do this. There really is no easy fix to this.

The simplest possibility would be to create a csv file (or maybe in a JSON string) to save the list entries. Save it every time `onPause` is called then retrieve the list `onResume` and repopulate the list. This is kind of fragile since it relies on the devices filesystem.

Another way to do this would be to integrate the SQLite features of Android. This is certainly the most elegant, robust and flexible way to do this. Save the data you want in the list in the SQLite DB `onPause` and retrieve it `onResume`.

How you want to do it is really your decision. Once you have found the solution which best fits your needs and you run into problems with your code just post a new question.

**Additional info:**

I have a similar app. The user creates a list. This list should stay as it is until they decide to delete an item from it.

Since my list displays a lot of detailed information and individual elements can change solution is: 
- I maintain the list data in a JSON structured file. And save that file on the device.
- Everytime the user adds or deletes an item or changes the data of an item on the list I make the changes to the `JSONObject` and save it to file.
- When the user reopens the app (maybe days or seconds later) the data is available in the JSON structured string in the file. 
- I parse this file and add the items to my list using a custom adapter.

If your todo list only contains simple single entry strings per list entry, then you could probably use a simple csv file. When the activity starts you will open the file. Perform a split in the contents of the file, which will give your an array of strings. You can use this array of strings to populate your list.

Comment: Ok. I’ll try it tonight and check back.

Comment: I'm afraid the data is still not being saved. Post updated with details and suggested code. If anything else is needed let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Obviously the data is being saved in the `SharedPreference` otherwise your `logcat` would not have displayed "My Iteration3" which was triggered by `onResume`

Comment: Yes sorry for not clarifying that detail. I’ll keep trying. Thanks for your time.